# Rails 4.2, AJAX form is submitted exponentially to the server on each subsequent triggering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a select on a form (company select), changing the option selected will update the possible options in another select (address select). The options of the address select are updated by submitting an AJAX request. The options of the address select are successfully updated each time.

However, when the first company is selected the AJAX get request is sent 1 time. When a second company is selected, the AJAX request is sent 2 times. Then 4, then 8, then 16, then 32 etc.

Not ideal...

Final note, i've been trying to follow Brandon Hilkert's advice on [organizing javascript.](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/)

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <%# Disables turbolinks caching of pages, to allow smooth animations %>
    <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'logos_and_banners/ecl_logo.png' %>
    <title>Environmental Concern Ltd - Your future in our hands.</title>

    <%# Geocompete JQuery plugin  %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDfo9YlYY6BnemhdpDMlQbo6li3RyRYO-0&libraries=places"></script>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/flash' %>
    <%= render 'shared/navigation/navigation' %>
    <%# console %>
  </html>
```

**app/views/licenses/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@company, @license], remote: true, html: {role: 'form'}) do |f| %>
  <%# errors will be loaded here via AJAX  %>
  <div id="form-errors" class="alert alert-danger collapse"></div>

  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.association :company,
            collection: Company.sorted_by('company_name_asc'),
            label_method: :company_name,
            value_method: :id,
            include_blank: false %>
      <%= f.association :address,
            collection: @company.addresses.sorted_by('site_name_asc'),
            label_method: :site_name,
            value_method: :id,
            include_blank: true %>
      <span class="help-block">
        Certain License types are related to a specific Address, others are only linked to the Company.
      </span>
      <%= f.input :license_type,
            collection: License::ALL_VALID_LICENSE_TYPES %>
      <%= f.input :license_name, as: :hidden%>
      <%= f.input :license_no %>
      <%= f.input :expiry_date,
            as: :string,
            input_html: {
              data: {
                provide: 'datepicker', date_format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
              }
            }%>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/edit_new/save_button', locals: {model_name: find_model_name_for_view(@license)} %>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require cocoon
//= require turbolinks
//= require data-confirm-modal
//= require jquery.geocomplete
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//
//= require init
//= require licenses/app.form.js
```

**app/assets/javascripts/init.js**

```
window.App || (window.App = {});

// Define init function on the App object
App.init = function(){

  // Bootstrap tooltips. Must be manually enabled.
  $(function () {
    $('[data-tooltip="true"]').tooltip();
  })
};

// Call the init function on every page transition.
// $(document).ready functions don't fire with turbolinks
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  return App.init();
});
```

**app/assets/javascripts/licenses/app.form.js**

```
App.license = (function() {
  function licensesFormBehaviour() {

    //Update address select based on Company choice
    $('select#license_company_id').change(function() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'addresses',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {
          company_id: $("select#license_company_id option:selected").val()
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        }
      });
    });

  // Several other unrelated methods, which function fine.
  // I've omitted them to make the code block shorter.

  return licensesFormBehaviour;
})();

$(document).on("ajaxSuccess", function() {
  //Licenses form only
  if (!($("form.edit_license").length > 0) && !($("form.new_license").length > 0) ) {
    return;
  }
  //invoke
  var license = new App.license();
  return license;
});
```

Thanks for you time,
Patrick.

*Edit:*

Response, requested by fanta.

**AJAX response**

```
// Within the append() I've omitted around 30 additional <option> tags, for readability. 
$("#license_address_id").empty().append("<option value=\"\"></option><option value=\"197\">Berge Knolls<\/option>");
```

Comment: what's the response for the AJAX request ?, you might be biding the events on every request.

Comment: ohh, hold on, it looks to me that the `on("ajaxSuccess")` is binding your events over and over after you select a new company.

Comment: Hi fanta. Do you know how to only bind an event if not already bound? I will add the AJAX response to the original question.

Comment: why don't you do it just like you did it for `App.init()` ?, try with `on("turbolinks:load")` in your `app.form.js` file and there just call the `App.license()` function.

Comment: I think, ideally, I should be structuring my javascript to only call the relevant code once. However, I'm a novice in javascript.

Comment: The form is remote i.e. loaded via an AJAX get request after the initial page load. So it needs to be bound to AjaxSuccess somewhere, for the javascript hook into the AJAX inserted content.

Comment: did you manage to fix this ?. If not, try removing the `ajaxSuccess` and replace it with `$(document).ready...`. Or try calling `license` as soon as your html is rendered without listening to any event. In any case you just need to find a way to bind only once the event. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you load in the form via ajax, and hence initialise the form on `ajaxSuccess`, but as fanta mentioned in the comments, licences are also being initialised after the select request is complete, resulting in multiple instances.

To solve this, you could store the `licence` instance in a data property, and only initialise if it does not already exist on the form element:

```
$(document).on("ajaxSuccess", function() {
  $("form.edit_license, form.new_license").each(function(i, form) {
    var $form = $(form);
    var license = $form.data('license');
    if (!license) $form.data('license', new App.license());
  })
});
```

---

**Bonus stuff**: Rails (or rather [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)) already gives you the select/AJAX behaviour for free! :)

If you add `data-remote`, `data-url`, and `data-method` to your select element, jquery-ujs will serialise the value of the element make the request for you. In your case, with simple_form, this is a little trickier, but if the documentation is correct, then you may be able to do something like:

```
<%= f.input :company do %>
  <%= f.select
    :company,
    options_from_collection_for_select(
      Company.sorted_by('company_name_asc'), 'id', 'company_name'
    ),
    { include_blank: false },
    data: {
      remote: true,
      method: 'get',
      url: addresses_path
    }
  %>
<% end %>
```

When the select changes, jquery-ujs, will `GET` to `/addresses?company_id=:selected_id`, where your response can take over.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response Dom. I'll try both solutions later today or tomorrow then accept your answer.

Comment: (BTW the first bit is the main solution, the bonus stuff just means you won't have to manually write the ajax call :)

Comment: Small typo Dom. Replace 'var $form' with 'var form' and we're good to go. Thanks again, this works and I'm now reading about why.

Furthermore, thanks for the bonus tip, I also implemented it.

Comment: @PatrickQuigley glad to hear it! and thanks for spotting that typo (now fixed)